# lldb command jump: resume outside the current function?

Tags: xcode, lldb

LLDB command `jump` lets me resume program execution at a different position from where it has stopped, but it seems to be restricted to addresses inside the current function:

```
(lldb) jump CLI.cpp:15
error: CLI.cpp:15 is outside the current function.
```

I'm curious about that, since this restriction is not documented in `lldb`'s help, and the syntax `jump <file>:<line>` somehow indicates that one could use arbitrary entry points:

> ```
> (lldb) help jump
>      ('_regexp-jump')  Set the program counter to a new address.  Expects 'raw'
>      input (see 'help raw-input'.)
>
> Syntax: 
> _regexp-jump <line>
> _regexp-jump +<line-offset> | -<line-offset>
> _regexp-jump <file>:<line>
> _regexp-jump *<addr>
>
> 'jump' is an abbreviation for '_regexp-jump'
> ```

I'm aware that resuming in a different frame/stack may bring the program into an inconsistent state with "wonderful" side effects.

How can I jump to lines outside the current function in `lldb` (ignoring possible side effects)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jump` is a wrapper command that packages up some common uses of the underlying `thread jump` into a compact form.  That's what all the `_regex-` commands are in lldb.  Do:

```
(lldb) help command regex
```

if you want more details on this regex commands, and of course

```
(lldb) help thread jump
```

for everything you can do with that command.

The wrapper doesn't have an affordance to allow jumping outside the current function because that is definitely NOT a safe operation, so the default is to assume you made a mistake in typing the line or file name...

The underlying command does have a `--force` option that allows you to move the pc out of the current function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `thread jump -r -l 15 -f CLI.cpp` followed by pressing continue did the job. With that, I can re-enter code to be analyzed, again triggering breakpoints, without having to click through the app or start the whole program to get to the point of interest again. Of course, as expected, the app is not functioning properly afterwards, but it's just for debugging...

Comment: Note that another way to debug random functions in lldb is to set a breakpoint on the function, then call it by hand in lldb using `expr -i 0 -- myfunc()`  You can then step around in the function, looking at whatever, and when you are done either type  `continue` to finish the function call and see what the return would be, or run `thread return -x` to terminate the expression evaluation and return to the previous program state.  The only harm that does is whatever side effects the function you called had.